# SwiftUI - button label rendered twice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Not sure when this started happening, but it seems like [`Button`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button) labels get duplicated now. Take this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            active.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle")
                .onChange(of: active) { newValue in
                    print("Active changed to: \(newValue)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It renders fine <kbd>[image: Button that says Toggle]</kbd>, but check the console:

> Active changed to: true
> Active changed to: true

Why is `Active changed to: true` printed twice?

I suspect SwiftUI evaluates the label twice, but only shows the label on the second pass. I did some testing with `UIViewRepresentable` — its `makeUIView` function should only be called once. Yet it's called 2 times:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            active.toggle()
        } label: {
            InnerViewRepresentable()
        }
    }
}

struct InnerViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        print("Making view")
        return UIView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

> Making view
> Making view

Any thoughts? I'm running Xcode 14.0 beta 3 (14A5270f) on the iOS 16.0 simulator. This is probably a relative minor issue, but it broke some of my view modifiers that relied on `onChange`.

Comment: Tested first code using xcode  (On Version 13.2.1 (13C100)), found no issue , just because the print called twice , we cannot say that the button renders twice , because it is inside the onChange ( so, given closure t the onChange is called when the given variable value changed , not when the UI renders)

Comment: @Yodagama good to know, thanks. But if I only called `active.toggle()` once, why would it print twice? Also have you tried adding the `UIViewRepresentable`?

Comment: This looks like a bug - worth submitting to Apple.